# Integrating Rebus with Legacy Systems

Tags: rebus

Sometimes we need to integrate our existing legacy systems with new workflows and Microservices developed with frameworks like rebus.

Many a time the applications are developed using languages and technologies that are sometimes awkward to incorporate these workflows.

I think there is a room for Rebus to chip in in this area especially as rebus can use SQL Server or other databases for queueing messages. What is needed is a simple way to create messages from lets say stored procedures or triggers into a table queue.

What is the best way to do it bearing in mind that there are some database versions that do not support json data types such as SQL Server versions <2016 ?.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way, in general, is to use the ["channel adapter" pattern](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ChannelAdapter.html), which basically means that you write small programs at the periphery of your system that take care of integrating the legacy apps with your message-driven architecture.

If you want to integrate with SQL Server, the channel adapters can be a small program that looks for changes in the database and publishes those changes as event on the bus.

A good way to implement that, is to have triggers write to a sequence-numbered event log of sorts in the database, and then a small app on the side will catch up to events from the event log and publish them, keeping track of its read position.

You *could* of course also try and hook into Rebus' transport and e.g. make a trigger in SQL Server write messages to a table used by Rebus for messages, but that's much harder, and it's more brittle, because your integration will have a much broader interface towards the world.... so I would not recommend this approach!

Also, one of the nice things with Rebus is that you can switch to RabbitMQ some time down the road when you find out that building stuff with messages is cool, and your total required message throughput exceeds what SQL Server can handle... if your integration makes assumptions about Rebus' transport, then that switch would be much harder.

Just my two cents.